# Window.location won't redirect?

Tags: javascript

JavaScript is not redirecting. Once setting to iOS user-agent, I tried the following:

1. Place the code within HEAD tag;
2. Change URL to google.com -- the code below works OK;
3. Change window.location.replace to href
4. Confirm Test condition evaluates to TRUE;

   ```
   (function (a) {
       iDevice = /ip(hone|od|ad)/i.test(a);
   })(navigator.userAgent || navigator.vendor || window.opera);

   if (iDevice) {
       setTimeout("window.location.replace('https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/hirecandy/id884460557?mt=8')", 2000);
   }
   ```

I'm really confused why my landing page is not redirecting?!!! The code is working for all other URLs...

Comment: Why not convert it to a function? I'm talking about the text inside setTimeout.

Comment: is your code actually running through the `if(iDevice)` statement?

Comment: works fine, if iDevice is true

Comment: Try `window.location.href= 'https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/hirecandy/id884460557?mt=8';`

Comment: Strange, while the test condition evaluates to TRUE, window.location.replace fails???

Comment: I tried window.location.href (not preferred), but it didnt work...

Comment: Is the document containing this script loaded in a frame?

Comment: No frame. I placed it within HEAD or include js. Does it work for you in a plain html?